# Does using CSS hover affect Jquery on(click)

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

I am not sure why this isn't working. I created a hidden menu element that when you roll over it, it will display its contents which are a login and register button that should trigger a lightbox form.

html

```
<div id='container'>
  <div id='menu'>
     <div class='inputBut' id='loginBut'>Login</div>
     <div class='inputBut' id='regBut'>Register</div> 
  </div>
```

css

```
/*--------- Menu -----------------*/

  #menu {
    z-index:10;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4%;
    transition: height 0.125s ease;
    background-color: black;
  }

  #menu:hover {
    height: 10%;
  }

  #menu:hover .inputBut{
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .inputBut{
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 30%;
    border: solid 2px white;
    border-radius: .5em;
    width:4em;
    padding-left:2em;
    padding-right: 2em;
    text-align: center;
  }

/*-------------------- form styling ------------------*/
.lightBox{
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: rgba(10,10,10,.9);
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

js

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(init);

function init(){
  login();
}


function login(){
  $("#loginBut").click(function(){
    $("#container").append("<div class='lightBox closeBox'><form id='loginForm'><input type='text' id='email'/><input type='text' id='password'><input type='submit'></form></div>");
  });
}
```

Does using the css :hover to change the display settings not let me use the $('#loginBut') selector?

Comment: Its working here http://jsfiddle.net/Hk8c5/. What is the actual problem?

Comment: Use `Inspect Element` feature of Chrome to see if there's any javascript error in your site

Comment: It works, I don't know why it wasn't working on my browswer for 20 minutes. Thanks for your help. How can I close a question?